# Status Code: Forbidden when attempting to create a subscription to mail events

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm attempting to use the `/subscriptions` endpoint of Microsoft Graph but I'm getting the following response:

```php
stdClass Object
(
    [error] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => ExtensionError
            [message] => Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: Forbidden]
            [innerError] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [request-id] => 15acd5eb-46db-408e-8c6b-3bb779d63940
                    [date] => 2017-09-29T17:44:45
                )   
        )
)
```

In the Microsoft Application Registration Portal, I have Application Permissions `Mail.Read` and `User.Read.All` granted to my application.

I'm following [this documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/subscription_post_subscriptions).

Immediately prior to the call to `/subscriptions` I'm successfully retrieving an access token and using it to retrieve user information from the `/users` endpoint.

I'm using PHP curl to make these requests:

```php
$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/";

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$token;
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';

$postData = array (
         "changeType" => "created,updated",
         "notificationUrl" => "https://example.com/subscriptionListener.php",
         "resource" => "users/GUID-of-a-user/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages",
         "expirationDateTime" => "2017-10-01T18:23:45.9356913Z",
         "clientState" => "12345"
        );

$postJSON = json_encode($postData);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($postData));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postJSON);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo "<pre>", print_r(json_decode($result), 1), "</pre>";
```

My confirmation endpoint (`subscriptionListener.php`) is being called with a validation token, but if I send an email to the account I subscribed to I'm not getting the notification.

UPDATE: I pasted my token into a [token debugger](https://jwt.io/) and found that my token shows a role of:

```
  "roles": [
    "User.Read.All"
  ],
```

The subscription endpoint requires `Mail.Read`, which according to the Microsoft Application Portal my app has:
[image: Microsoft Application Portal Permissions]

So it looks like my application permissions aren't being reflected in my token.

Any assistance greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured this out... I had failed to provide "admin consent" for the new `Mail.Read` permissions.

I found the answer [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tsmatsuz/2016/10/07/application-permission-with-v2-endpoint-and-microsoft-graph/), in the section titled 'Admin Consent.' You just type in the url as indicated, then after you sign in click 'Accept'. Note that the `redirect_uri` parameter doesn't have to work - if it doesn't, then when you click 'Accept' you'll get an error message, but the Admin Consent will still have been granted.